# Object level permissions and roles using JWT authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, database-design, jwt

I'd like to use JWT permission scopes to control object-level permissions, e.g. if I have some models such as:

**Organization** hasMany **Branch** hasMany **Employee**

I want to limit editing of *Employees* to *admins that belong to that organization*.

I'm thinking the JWT will look something like:

```
{ permissions: ['123:admin' ] }
```

A user with this token will then be able to edit any employees under Organization 123.

A permissions check will be applied to the **PATCH /Employees/{id}** endpoint, but will have to look up the owned organization of the employee before authorizing access.

Would this be a reasonable approach for this type of problem, or are there more established patterns in handling object level permissions?

Comment: This is relatively broad, and I'm not sure it has much to do with JWT.  After all, you're just using JWTs to transport information you already know (what permissions a particular user has) from one part of your system to another.